# Fazer uma busca e subtração de datas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

sou novo na área e gostaria de colocar uma dificuldade que estou tendo ..
No banco mongo tenho um exemplo de tabela (retornando essse json)

```
{
  "_id": "5cb7652fc278309ac78dce2b",
  "status": "Teste 123",
  "accessTokenKey": "exemplo",
  "accessTokenSecret": "exemplo",
  "dateToPost": "2019-04-15T14:45:28Z",
  "dateTime": "2019-04-17T17:41:03Z",
  "isPosted": false,
  "__v": 0
}
```

Primeiro de tudo eu preciso fazer o seguinte...

Comparar o `dateToPost` com a hora atual para que se a hora atual for maior, um outro util entra em ação e envia o post (é um app para postar no twitter com agendamento, apenas para estudo), depois ele muda o estado do `isPosted` de `false`, para `true`

Eu empaquei aqui, se nao quiser falar a resposta me fala por gentileza como procurar já está de ótimo tamanho, desde já muito obrigado

Obs: eu consigo filtrar também com este código

```
Tweet.find({isPosted: false}, await function(err, tweets) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(tweets);
  })
}
```

mas nao consigo pegar as propriedade de dateToPost para subtrair =/

Answer (score 0):

Essa query compara se a propriedade (`dateToPost`) é menor ou igual (`$lte`) a data atual (`new Date()`)

```
Tweet.find({isPosted: false, dateToPost: { $lte: new Date() }}, () => { ... });
```

Há outros comparadores, olhe na [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/)